# html css ul and button issue

Tags: html, css

Hi so in this my explore more button and my ul list so whenever I move my explore button line height the ul and button both move together side..and I want the explore more button downward. what should I do?? I tried using other attributes but nothing worked. I am making this website for my dad's academy.

### Here is my  HTML code

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
    <div class="row">
         
        <div>
    <ul class="main-nav"> 
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Study Visa</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="">Australia</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Canada</a></li>
       <li><a href="">New Zealand</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Courses</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="">Ielts</a></li>
       <li><a href="">PTE</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Spoken English</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
     </li>
     <li> <a href="#"> Login </a> </li>
     <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
      <div class="button">
       <a href="" class="btn btn-two"> Explore More</a>    
        </div>    
                
        </div>
        </header>
                
    </header>
    </body>
```

this is my CSS code

```
body {
     background:  url(abc.jpg) no-repeat;
     background-size: none;
     background-position : none;
     background-size : cover;
     margin-left: 20%;
    }
    .main-nav
     {
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     list-style: none;
     font-family: arial;
     position: absolute
     top : 20px;
    }
    
    .main-nav li {
     float: left;
     
     width: 145px;
     height: 67px;
     
     background-color: black;
     opacity: 0.8;
     line-height: 67px;
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 22px; 
    margin-left : px;
    }
    
    .main-nav li a {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: white;
     display: block;
     line-height : 100 px ;
    }
    
    .main-nav li a:hover {
     background-color: orange;
    }
    
    .main-nav li ul li{
     display: none;
    }
    
    .main-nav li:hover ul li {
     display: block;
    
    }.button
    {
        margin-top: 350px;
        margin-left: 320px;
    }
    
    .btn
    {
        border: 1px solid white;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-right: 89px;
        font-size: 13px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    
    .btn-two
    {
        font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    }
    
    
    .btn-two:hover
    {
        background-color: darkorange;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
        
            
    }
```

so I want the menu above near k academy logo.. and explore more button where it is. thanks!!

[image]

Comment: Make a jsfiddle snippet for us pl0x

Comment: What are the `.row` styles?

Comment: Your HTML is a little malformatted as well. You have an open header tag at the top and 2 closing header tags down below. This is not the cause of the issue, but should be addressed

Comment: i had to edit the code as it was not posting my question because my code was very long as compared to the query i had written. So it got messed up there. The code is in proper format otherwise

Answer (score 0):

I changed up your HTML structure since there were empty tags and random closing tags. CSS i basically just removed the float on the li, since that takes it out of the flow, and instead added flexbox to the ul. Hope that helps flexbox ftw. Idk how your button ended up in that location but I would use `position: absolute` on that `top,right,bottom,left:0 margin: auto;`

```css
body {
  background: url(abc.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: none;
  background-position: none;
  background-size: cover;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  alig margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: arial;
}

.main-nav li {
  width: 145px;
  height: 67px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  line-height: 67px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-left: px;
}

.main-nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  line-height: 100 px;
}

.main-nav li a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

.main-nav li ul li {
  display: none;
}

.main-nav li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}

.button {
  margin-top: 350px;
  margin-left: 320px;
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 89px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn-two {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.btn-two:hover {
  background-color: darkorange;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>

    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Study Visa</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Australia</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Canada</a></li>
          <li><a href="">New Zealand</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Courses</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Ielts</a></li>
          <li><a href="">PTE</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Spoken English</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> Login </a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="button">
      <a href="" class="btn btn-two"> Explore More</a>
    </div>


  </header>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you to solve the problem.

```css
.main-menu {
  background-color: #444;
}
.main-menu nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.main-menu nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}
.main-menu nav > ul > li a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: .3s;
}
.main-menu nav > ul > li:hover > a {
    color: #7AA93C;
}
.main-menu nav ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    top: 150%;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: .3s;
}
.main-menu nav ul li:hover ul {
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
.main-menu nav ul li ul li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.main-menu nav ul li ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 6px 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #444;
    transition: .3s;
}
.main-menu nav ul li ul li:hover a {
    color: #7AA93C;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-menu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <!-- submenu start -->
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- submenu end -->
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Service</a>
        <!-- submenu start -->
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- submenu end -->
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: You can check the codepen link.   https://codepen.io/hnasir770/pen/yKpyPd